# MySQL select statement not returning rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple SELECT statement that I'm using in PHP:

```
$vote=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `votes` where username = '$big_hand_username' AND 
`voter` = '$user_name'");
```

When using this statement I don't get any rows returned. I should get 1 row returned. I only have one row in the votes table and it contains the username field that matches variable $big_hand_username.  $big_hand_username & $user_name both contain data and I've echoed them out to make sure.

However, when I just select all from votes table I get 1 row returned, which you'd expect. I can also select all from another table using the same variable:

```
$vote=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` where username = '$big_hand_username'");
```

This returns 1 row, which you'd expect as it contains a row containing the matching the field username.

I just can't understand why I can't get a row returned from votes table using the first select statement. Am I missing something? Could it be something to do with construction of the table? I've also tried running through while loop after the select statement but can't see anything wrong. Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Did you try to output the query itself and run it manually?

Comment: echo out the query and run that query direct into mysql

Comment: Double check that your variables are what you expect them to be, also echo out the entire (with generated variables included) SQL query and try to run it in phpMyAdmin (or similar).

Comment: Have tried using print_r($vote); to see what the SQL statement looks like and also tried echo $vote; but just returning resource id#8.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$vote=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `votes` where username = '".$big_hand_username."' AND 
voter = '".$user_name."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$vote = mysql_query("
            SELECT * FROM votes 
            WHERE username = '{$big_hand_username}' 
            AND voter = '{$user_name}'
        ");
```

Answer (score 0):

try bellow lines

```
$sql="
        SELECT * FROM votes 
        WHERE username = '{$big_hand_username}' 
        AND voter = '{$user_name}'
    ";
echo $sql; // for debuging also user_name,big_hand_username check
// for preventing sql-injection
$vote=mysql_query($sql);
```